# Grammar for a custom SQL function/extension

Tags: parsing, grammar, language-design

I'm looking to add a unique function in SQL that allows performing a custom aggregation, similar to how Airtable or Numbers does it. For example:

[image]

The preliminary syntax I had for this `GROUPING_ROWS` function thus far was:

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY 
-- The below is the part we are adding in
GROUPING_ROWS (
  Product SUBTOTALS Revenue:SUM(Revenue), Units:SUM(Units)
)
```

Does this seem like a straightforward syntax? The tricky thing is to allow for (1) multiple grouping levels; (2) multiple subtotals; and (3) custom aggregation calculations. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table
GROUP BY GROUPING_ROWS (
  Product SUBTOTALS Revenue:SUM(Revenue), Units:SUM(Units),COUNT(Units), SUM(Units*1.2) withInflation ;  
  Year    SUBTOTALS Revenue:SUM(Revenue)

)
```

To support the following, here is the grammar to support this:

```
GROUPING_ROWS (
    field_name SUBTOTAL[S] field_name:expr [AS alias] [, ...] [, ...] [; ...]
)
```

I have two questions related to this:

1. Does this grammar seem unambiguous and 'valid' so to speak?
2. Does the syntax/grammar seem inelegant/hack-y (maybe the semi-colon?) If so, what might be ways to improve it?

---

Finally, to re-iterate, I'm only interested in the grammar not the implementation against a database.

Comment: How do you plan to implement this?  What database platform?

Comment: @OldProgrammer it would use the Postgres SQL parser, but the actual function would be 'parsed away' and then transformed into two sql statements that is to be executed against the database -- one that grabs the rows and another that grabs the subtotals. So, it's handled at the parsing stage but not at the database-execution level, if that makes sense.

Comment: How is this different from `ROLLUP`? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS

Comment: @TheImpaler it's not an aggregation really -- it returns all the rows un-modified, with just a grouping 'parent' row showing subtotals.